# How to return an object with the number of grouped rows plus the group by field value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I'm on C#, .NET 4, and using LINQ I need to group all rows in a table, due to a fixed field, returning that groupby field value and the number of each rows grouped thanks to that clause.

The code I wrote is:

```
var result = (from p in db.MyPersons
              group p by new { p.IDPerson } into g
              select new
              {
                  IDPerson = g.Key.IDPerson,
                  Counter = g.Sum(p => p.IDPerson)
              });
```

but it returns `IDPerson` on both `IDPerson` and `Counter` field in the new generated object.

What's the mistake? It seems `Sum` doesn't sum?

Comment: `and the number of each rows grouped` so you want `Counter = g.Count()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the *number* of rows in the group use `Count` instead: (note you don't need an anonymous type either)

```
var result = (from p in db.MyPersons
              group p by p.IDPerson into g
              select new
              {
                  IDPerson = g.Key,
                  Counter = g.Count()
              });
```

`Sum` would *add up* all of the `IDPerson` values in the group - which would return the same value as `IDPerson` if there were only one item in the group.

Comment: Uhm. But what (for learning) if now I want another field of the table on the returning object? Let say, the field `surname`. Should I need to specify it on group by? I can't do (for what I see) `TheSurname = g.Surname` inside the select.

Comment: Well, you have a group of items now, so _which_ surname?  If all rows with the same `IDPerson` have the same surname then you can either group by `surname` as well (in which case you _do_ need an anonymous type), or you can use `g.First().surname` in the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by more than one column, you can do this:

```
var result = (from p in db.MyPersons
              group p by new{ p.IDPerson, p.Surname} into g
              select new
              {
                  IDPerson = g.Key,
                  Surname=g.Surname,
                  Counter = g.Count()
              });
```